# range datepicker multiple inputs works only with 1st field

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to dynamically add range datePicker but to better understand it I created 4 fields and tried to work with it but I'm stuck.
The third field keeps the data the first field has same with the forth and second field, when I change the data in the 3rd it changes what the 1st has...

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Calendrier.js">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Adresse.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="periodes" >
      <a>Période 1:</a> <br>
      <label for="dateFrom">Du</label>
      <input type="text" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" class="dateFrom">
      <label for="dateTo">Au</label>
      <input type="text" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" class="dateTo">
    </div>

    <div id="periodes" >
      <a>Période 2:</a> <br>
      <label for="dateFrom">Du</label>
      <input type="text" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" class="dateFrom">
      <label for="dateTo">Au</label>
      <input type="text" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" class="dateTo">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here my function:

```
 $( function() {
  var dateFormat = "dd-mm-yy",
      dateFrom = $( ".dateFrom" )
  .datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1
  })
  .on( "change", function() {
    dateTo.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
  }),
      dateTo = $( ".dateTo" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1
      })
  .on( "change", function() {
    dateFrom.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
  });

  function getDate( element ) {
    var date;
    try {
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
    } catch( error ) {
      date = null;
    }
    console.log(date);
    return date;
  }
} );
```

Comment: Don't use duplicate Id in html. Change it to different ID and code will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try to change the id of the second div in "periodes2" and the inputs in id="dateFrom2"and id="dateTo2" :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Calendrier.js">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Adresse.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="periodes" >
      <a>Période 1:</a> <br>
      <label for="dateFrom">Du</label>
      <input type="text" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" class="dateFrom">
      <label for="dateTo">Au</label>
      <input type="text" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" class="dateTo">
    </div>

    <div id="periodes2" >
      <a>Période 2:</a> <br>
      <label for="dateFrom">Du</label>
      <input type="text" id="dateFrom2" name="dateFrom" class="dateFrom">
      <label for="dateTo">Au</label>
      <input type="text" id="dateTo2" name="dateTo" class="dateTo">
    </div>

<script>
    $( function() {
  var dateFormat = "dd-mm-yy",
      dateFrom = $( ".dateFrom" )
  .datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1
  })
  .on( "change", function() {
    dateTo.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
  }),
      dateTo = $( ".dateTo" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1
      })
  .on( "change", function() {
    dateFrom.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
  });

  function getDate( element ) {
    var date;
    try {
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
    } catch( error ) {
      date = null;
    }
    console.log(date);
    return date;
  }
} );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to add the second datepicker dynamically so I have to use the class, and the script uses $( ".dateTo" ) and  $( ".dateFrom")

Comment: if you want affect the both couple of datepicker with the script, you can use my example because i change the id, but not the class. So $( ".dateTo" ) and $( ".dateFrom") will affect the both couple of datepicker. But if you want affect separatly each couple of datepicker, you have to change the class of the second couple in class="dateFrom2" and class="dateTo2" and do another function witch uses $( ".dateTo2" ) and $( ".dateFrom2")